# prevent jquery mobile from styling all elements except for some

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm aware that if I use jQuery Mobile, it will effect all elements on a page, except for elements I add data-role="none" to.

Is there a way to have jQuery Mobile effect nothing except for the elements I wish to opt-in?

Answer (score 1):

See **[`ignoreContentEnabled`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)**

> Once set, all automatic enhancements made by the framework to each
>   enhanceable element of the user's markup will first check for a
>   data-enhance=false parent node. If one is found the markup will be
>   ignored. This setting and the accompanying data attribute provide a
>   mechanism through which users can prevent enhancement over large
>   sections of markup.

You can implement like so:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.extend( $.mobile , {
    ignoreContentEnabled: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, So, I believe I add this to the top of my page before jQuery Mobile loads.

Do you know what the next step is?

I don't understand what the "data-enhance=false parent node" is.

I was hoping the process would be like:
1) Globally tell jQueryMobile to effect nothing by default.
2) add something such as data-role="on" for elements you want it to effect.

I'm a little confused if the process described in ignoreContentEnabled is describing a similar process or not.

Comment: It will check parent nodes for `data-enhance="false"`. If it finds one, the node in question will be ignored by jQuery mobile.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, I should add data-enhance="false" to something like the 1st main sections div tag, and then for a theoretical 2nd section where I want jQueryMobile to effect, I don't put anything. Essentially, it's like a data-role="none" that works on parent elements. Do I have that correct?